# Outlook addins: Data refresh in the Taskpane

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an Outlook Taskpane add-in. In the Taskpane we are fetching data from an API and showing the result in the taskpnae.

However the data is getting cached at the Outlook Client and at times, the taskpane still shows older data.Is there any way we can force the taskpane to always load the data from the Server rather than Outlook cache.

I have tried to modify the IE Settings, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you talking about when the user reopens the taskpane or a different scenario? In any case, since it's your addin code fetching the data to show in taskpane, your addin should have full control of how often your code runs to fetch data from the server. Is there anything in the addins platform preventing your code to fetch the data when you need to and showing the result?

Comment: Yes, when the user re-opens the taskpane, the taskpane doesn't load the updated data in Outlook Client. However in OWA the  taskpane is always updated.

Comment: Some more clarification is needed here. What API's are you calling for data? Why can't these just be called when the Taskpane isopened? What is preventing that from happening? Also what Outlook Client are you on (Mac, Win32 Desktop)? What is the build number? What version of Windows (if applicable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with axios and IE 11. Apparently IE caches the API response and even though the request was hitting the server everytime the response was being fetched from cache. Adding the Pragma header like below to the axios request solved the issue.

> headers: {'Pragma': 'no-cache'}